# protractor not stopping selenium server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

We are getting a timeout error after our protractor tests have completed.

```
Error updating Sauce pass/fail status: 'Could not send request: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

We have tried adding these to the `onComplete` function in our `conf.js`: 
`browser.driver.quit()`, `browser.driver.stop()`, and different forms like this. None seem to be stopping the web driver. for the `stop()` function we are obviously receiving the error that the function DNE. For the `browser.driver.quit()`, we are receiving the timeout still. How do we stop the webdriver?

My protractor version: `Version 3.3.0`

My Complete conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
  sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
  tunnelIdentifier: process.env.SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER,

  webDriverProxy: 'my-companies-proxy',

  specs: ['e2e/*spec.js'],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  onPrepare: function(){
     var caps = browser.getCapabilities()
  },

 multiCapabilities: [{
   browserName: 'chrome',
   version: '41',
   platform: 'Windows 7',
   name: "chrome-tests",
   shardTestFiles: true,
   maxInstances: 25
 }],

 onComplete: function() {

   var printSessionId = function(jobName){
     browser.getSession().then(function(session) {
       console.log('SauceOnDemandSessionID=' + session.getId() + ' job-name=' + jobName);
    });
   }
  printSessionId("Protractor Tests");
  browser.driver.quit();
 }
}
```

Comment: In my experience, we put `'tunnel-identifier': process.env.SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER` inside the multiCapabilities (along with browserName and platform and such). And we print the `SauceOnDemandSessionID` inside onPrepare instead of onComplete. You shouldn't have to do anything in the onComplete section.